# Replace all line breaks with a space in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a `UITextView`. I want to disable all line breaks in the text view, whether they're typed manually or if the user pastes text that contains line breaks, and replace each line break with a space (" ").

How would I go about doing this? What function should I be making use of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITextViewDelegate`'s [`textViewDidChange(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange) method to listen whenever the text view's text changes. Inside here, you can then replace all occurrences of a newline (`\n`) with an empty String (`""`).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
        textView.text = text
    }
}
```

| Without `textViewDidChange(_:)` | With `textViewDidChange(_:)` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: User hits return and a new line is added. When they paste a string containing a new line, the new line is also added.] | [image: User hits return but no new line is added. Any pasted string that contains a new line removes the new line.] |